# Why there are 6 Base Address Registers (BARs) in PCIe endpoint?

Tags: pci, pci-e, base-address

After some reading about the PCIe, I came around the PCI compatible configuration headers and after understanding the header there is Base address Register(BAR) field. Where there are total 6 BARs in each PCIe endpoint. Why there are 6 BARs and not just 2 (1 in case 32 bit address and 2 in case 64 bit). I mean what is the detailed functionality of all the BARs?
[image: PCI Express PCI-Compatible Configuration Header]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use of the BARs varies by device. They are used either for device control operations (this is the usual case) or for data transfer to/from the device. The reason there are six slots is to allow devices to provide different regions for different purposes. Also, since the interface supports 64-bit address spaces, providing one of those requires a 64-bit BAR (which requires two contiguous 32-bit slots) to configure the base address.

One example of the BAR usage can be seen in the datasheet for the [Intel i350 Ethernet Controller](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/ethernet-controller-i350-datasheet.pdf). See section 9.4.11. There are 3 BARs in this device: one for memory-mapped device configuration (and access to a FLASH device), one for device configuration via I/O address space, and one for configuring MSI-X interrupt vectors.

Other devices may have one BAR or five (or none if the device is a bridge). If you're running linux, try `sudo lspci -vv` on your system to observe the variations among devices.